# USB Type-C Switch for Monitor Sharing between PCs

Tags: usb, kvm, usb-c

I want to share a pair of Dell S2719DC 27" QHD (2560 x 1550 @ 59 Hz) resolution USB-C monitors between two 2018 MacBook Pros. The MacBooks dual-boot to run either MacOS 10.15 Catalina and Windows 10 (work & personal). Each MacBook can drive two monitors by USB-C as is.

I'd like a USB-C matrix switch with four USB-C inputs and two USB-C outputs, so I can  plug each laptop's 2 USB-C ports into the switch, and decide which PC uses the monitors at any moment. I've done a lot of Googling and come up empty.

This effectively, but all using USB Type-C connectors:

```
Monitor    Monitor
   |          |
   +----++----+
        ||
      Switch
      ||  ||
 +----+|  |+----+
 |+----+  +----+|
 ||            ||
Work          Home
Laptop      Laptop
```

Does anyone know if such a product exists?

Thanks in advance,

Steve.

Comment: Hi K7AAY, yes I can. I'm just fed up of physically swapping both cables depending upon what I'm doing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking in interest in finding a solution. Both machines are 2018 MacBooks dual-booted to run macOS and Windows. The monitors are Dell 27" QHD resolution. Both machines are capable of running 2 QHD monitors. The main thing is I just don't want to keep unplugging 2x USB cables between machines when I switch from work code to personal code.

Comment: Latest versions of macOS and Windows BTW (on both laptops). The monitors are Dell S2719DC.

Comment: Hi, yep, the displays are side-by-side. The refresh rate is 59Hz. That switch looks like it may do the job, but wow, it's expensive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A pair of [Acroname Programmable Industrial USB Type-C 4-Port Switches](http://acroname.com/store/s85-pass-usbcsw?sku=S85-RDVR-USBCSW) controlled by a NUC, micro PC, or creaky old lappie could do the trick. Sure wish they had a [manual switch](https://images.app.goo.gl/cpN1PhopxXybGR1W9), though, to make switching easy.

USB-C [3.2 for video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) is so new, and devices for all the different versions of USB-C are so inconsistently implemented because of all the things it can do, that we're just not seeing much stuff which ain't spendy.

==

Now, since the MacBookPro supports Thunderbolt 3 on the USB-C we have a less spendy solution.

2) StarTech.com has a [Thunderbolt 3 device](https://www.startech.com/AV/display-and-video-adapters/thunderbolt-3-video-adapters/thunderbolt-3-to-dual-hdmi~TB32HD24K60) with one USB-C 3.2 in, two 3.2 USB-C out. The second StarTech out port could be converted to HDM(I). Since your monitors also accept HDM(I), adding such a [conversion cable](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/9/1/12758384/usb-c-hdmi-alt-mode-cables-specifications) provides the second signal to each monitor. Then, an app which runs in Win10, an iOS phone/tablet or Android phone/tablet [tells your monitors to toggle](https://displayfusion.com/Features/RemoteControl) ([pro version](https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/)) between the USB-C 3.2 A/V data input to the monitor and the HDMI A/V data input to the monitor.